# why does following series diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am interested if following series diverges, what is a reason of this, series is given by

$1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1........$

there is two things which  we should pay attention, if  number of elements is  even, then clearly it's value is $0$, if it is odd, then it is $1$, I mean we can consider as a  function on we can say that, if $n$ is even, $f(x)=0$, else $f(x)=1$, maybe  we use  this fact that, if some partial sum converges,then series itself converges, else it diverges, is it reason why we say that this series diverges? thanks in advance

Comment: It diverges according to the usual definition of convergence of infinite series. If you rearrange the summands, you can get partial sums that are arbitrarily large (or small). (This is true for convergent series that are not absolutely convergent also.) P.S. I don't quite follow your argument regarding $n$ and $f(x)$ because I do not know the relation among the three symbols: $n, f$ and $x$.

Comment: i tried to imagine as a Piecewiese function

Comment: I think you have given insufficient information. Maybe it would help if you elaborate on what you have in mind. The big paragraph in your question is not very understandable as it is now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, we say $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^n = L$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $$\left|\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^n-L\right|<\varepsilon.$$

In this case, there is no such $N$.  Take, for example $\varepsilon=0.3$.  Then if we have $$\left|\sum_{i=0}^N (-1)^N-L\right|<0.3$$ we must have $$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{N+1} (-1)^{N+1}-L\right|>0.3.$$

So the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence of partial sum is (1,0,1,0,1,0...)

This sequence doesn't converge so the series doesn't converge!

Answer (score 0):

Your statement, "if some partial sum converges,then series itself converges" is wrong because of the word "some".  A series converges if and only if **the** sequence of partial sums converges.  As UNM said, the sequence of partial sums is 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ... which does not converge.